# RJDBC driver with crate do not find class

Tags: r, rstudio, rjdbc, crate

I am trying to create a RJDBC driver for crate. Whenever I ran

```
jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass = 'io.crate.client.jdbc.CrateDriver', '../../private/tmp/crate-jdbc-standalone-1.0.4.jar')
```

I got:

> Fehler (Error) in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found

I also tried:

```
jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass = 'io.crate.client.jdbc.CrateDriver', '../../private/tmp/crate-jdbc-standalone-1.0.4.jar', identifier.quote = '´')
```

That's the working MySQL driver:

```
jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver', '../../private/tmp/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar', identifier.quote = '´')
```

Let me finally point out, that this code runs properly on another machine.

The fact, that the MySQL driver works as well as the crate driver on a colleagues' machine keeps baffling me. I checked the paths a dozens of times. I tried different version of the crate jdbc driver (from 1.0.4 to 1.9).

**Question:** Is there any other way to address the CrateDriver.class in a way that R won't pretend it could not find it? Or is it OS X which can't work with anything newer than Java SE6, and this is the source of evil? Help's appreciated. I am kind of desperate right now and waste/spend the whole day on it.
-R

Answer (score 0):

It seems that RStudio is pulling the Mac OS X supplied Java 1.6 Runtime and have problems then if you want to include the Crate JDBC driver. Crate requires at least JRE 1.7. Maybe you can define a different/custom JDK for running RStudio.

Regards,
Michael

Comment: Thx, for helping Michael. But you've just reformulated my question as suggestion, haven't you? Actually, I am looking for a method to tell R which JDK to use. Do you know one?

Answer (score 0):

you can also define specific JAVA version for your script explicitly

`Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\\jdk7\\jre')`